# How to assign sequence of dates for every id in R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
 x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,9,9,10),dna=c(232,424,5345,45345,45,345,4543,345345,4545,2323,23,1222))
 date.seq <- as.Date(Sys.Date():as.Date("2014-09-10"))[1:length(unique(x$id))]
```

Here I do fill date corresponding to each id.

```
data.frame(x,Dates=rep(date.seq,data.frame(table(x$id))$Freq))
```

gives:

```
    id   dna      Dates
  1  1   232 2014-08-16
  2  1   424 2014-08-16
  3  1  5345 2014-08-16
  4  2 45345 2014-08-17
  5  2    45 2014-08-17
  6  7   345 2014-08-18
```

However, I would like to assign arbitrarily the length of sequence of dates. Desired output for date spanning over 3 id:

```
      id    dna      Dates
   1   1    232 16-08-2014
   2   1    424 16-08-2014
   3   1   5345 16-08-2014
   4   2  45345 16-08-2014
   5   2     45 16-08-2014
   6   7    345 16-08-2014
   7   7   4543 16-08-2014
   8   7 345345 16-08-2014
   9   7   4545 16-08-2014
   10  9   2323 17-08-2014
   11  9     23 17-08-2014
   12 10   1222 18-08-2014
```

Comment: How do you decide where the cutpoints are?

Comment: As suggested by Thomas, what are the rule behind the choice of (sequence of) dates ?

Comment: I would like to set the sequence myself. For example I would set 3 meaning the dates are distributed over 3 id. The dates would be taken in increasing order, the final date would be taken as needed from the vector of dates.

Comment: Three meaning three numbers in a row (1,2,3) or three in terms of the order they appear in your data (1,2,7)?

Comment: yes, as they appear in data..(1,2,7...)

Comment: if 3 is taken, the date 2014-08-16 should span over 3 ids, thats id=(1,2,7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a sequential list of `id`, and then use the divide operator to assign each id to a group.

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,7,7,7,7),dna=c(232,424,5345,45345,45,345,4543,345345,4545))
seq.id <- match(x$id,unique(x$id))

n <- 1
x$Dates <- Sys.Date() + (seq.id-1) %/% n
#   id    dna      Dates
# 1  1    232 2014-08-16
# 2  1    424 2014-08-16
# 3  1   5345 2014-08-16
# 4  2  45345 2014-08-17
# 5  2     45 2014-08-17
# 6  7    345 2014-08-18
# 7  7   4543 2014-08-18
# 8  7 345345 2014-08-18
# 9  7   4545 2014-08-18

n <- 2
x$Dates <- Sys.Date() + (seq.id-1) %/% n
#   id    dna      Dates
# 1  1    232 2014-08-16
# 2  1    424 2014-08-16
# 3  1   5345 2014-08-16
# 4  2  45345 2014-08-16
# 5  2     45 2014-08-16
# 6  7    345 2014-08-17
# 7  7   4543 2014-08-17
# 8  7 345345 2014-08-17
# 9  7   4545 2014-08-17

n <- 3
x$Dates <- Sys.Date() + (seq.id-1) %/% n
#   id    dna      Dates
# 1  1    232 2014-08-16
# 2  1    424 2014-08-16
# 3  1   5345 2014-08-16
# 4  2  45345 2014-08-16
# 5  2     45 2014-08-16
# 6  7    345 2014-08-16
# 7  7   4543 2014-08-16
# 8  7 345345 2014-08-16
# 9  7   4545 2014-08-16
```